# sql newbie trying to cross reference data in two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, cross-reference

I have two tables, `DATA_TABLE` and `ERROR_TABLE`. `DATA_TABLE` has a column `ID` with an 8 digit number. `ERROR_TABLE` has a column `KEY` with `idkey=` followed by eight digits.

I can't use an intersect because the tuples are different and I don't know how to work around it.

What I need is to find the rows in `DATA_TABLE` that have a value in the `ID` column that corresponds to a value in the `ERROR_TABLE` in the `KEY` column.

Here's a visual. I need to see which of these match and and display those rows from the `DATA_TABLE`

```
DATA_TABLE
  ID
  24294857
  19573859
  49205983

ERROR_TABLE
  KEY
  idkey=24294857
  idkey=66849896
  idkey=94697356
```

Comment: What database platform are you using? SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, Postgres...?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 3):

i would use a simple inner join

```
select * 
from DATA_TABLE 
inner join ERROR_COLUMN  
   on DATA_TABLE.ID = ERROR_TABLE.KEY
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select dt.* 
from data_table dt 
join error_table et 
   on et.idkey = dt.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to PM 77-1, but using an explicit join:

```
SELECT *
  FROM DATA_TABLE
  JOIN ERROR_TABLE
    ON 'idkey=' || ID = KEY;
```

See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dbe73/3

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM DATA_TABLE d, ERROR_TABLE e
WHERE ('idkey='||d.id = e.key)
ORDER BY DATA_TABLE.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do is correct your data in Error Table. These examples will cut the text leaving digits only. You may explicitly convert them to number with TO_NUMBER() function to join and compare. You already have plenty join examples. But before joining you need to convert both sides to number cutting off the characters in front of numbers:

```
-- This example assumes you will always have '=' in your string --
SELECT SUBSTR('idkey=24294857', INSTR('idkey=24294857', '=')+1) digits_only 
  FROM dual
/

SELECT regexp_replace('idkey=24294857','[^0-9]') digits_only 
  FROM dual; 
/

SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('idkey=24294857','[[:digit:]]+') AS digits_only FROM dual
/
```

After this your query will compare number to number in join, which is the only right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone!

I tried every suggestion, but couldn't get any to work. I'm really green with SQL and only understand a few commands.

Finally, I got this from a colleague ***and it accomplished what I need***. Now, I just need to understand it...

```
SELECT *
FROM DATA_TABLE
WHERE EXISTS 
        (SELECT NULL
           FROM ERROR_TABLE
          WHERE ID = SUBSTR(ERROR_TABLE.KEY,7));
```